# Use and meaning of "to VERB" clause

Tags: complementation

I am often confused about the construction of clauses with *to*.

> I saw that there was not much water left in the bottle, so I picked it up went to the kitchen refilled it.

Is this a possible contraction of the previous sentence? Is it acceptable?

> I picked up the bottle to refill it.

Similarly, is the following sentence acceptable?

> I saw the show to talk about it next morning at work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first sentence requires at least one comma and an *and*:

> I picked it up, went to the kitchen and refilled it.

"So* looks back to the previous clause to supply a reason—because the bottle was almost empty—for doing all three things  which follow, but does not explicitly state that you picked it up **in order to** refill it.

Consequently, it cannot be regarded as a ‘contraction’ (I think what you mean here is an *ellipsis*): it is a restatement, which asserts a purpose leaves out its realization in the two following actions: taking the bottle to the kitchen and actually refilling it. The sequence might have been interrupted before you completed it.

Likewise, the second sentence, *I saw the show to talk about it next morning at work*, asserts only your viewing and your purpose; it does not assert that you did in fact talk about the show the next morning.

Answer (score 2):

> <s>I saw that there was not much water left in the bottle, so I picked it up went to the kitchen refilled it.</s>

There is a problem with this sentence: you need to add commas.

> I saw that there was not much water left in the bottle, so I picked it up, [I] went to the kitchen, [and] [I] refilled it.

In very casual, informal writing you might leave out *and*, but it is normally compulsory. Leaving out *I* in the second and third clauses is perfectly normal and not informal at all. There is nothing unusual about *to*: it just introduces the direction of *went*, an adverbial phrase of direction.

> I picked up the bottle [in order] to refill it.

This is perfectly normal. You don't need *in order*: it means exactly the same thing. In a simple, clear sentence like this, using *to* to introduce a *purpose* with *to* + infinitive is standard. It has nothing directly to do with *to* as in the first sentence, where it introduces a direction.

> I saw the show to talk about it next morning at work.

This sentence is of the same type as the previous one: the reason/purpose why you saw the show is that you could talk about it the next morning. The situation is a bit unusual (is that really the main reason why you saw the show? Isn't that a bit silly?), but the grammar is fine.